# Python, openpyxl: how to preserve formating in the cell?

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

I am importing some data from xslx file to Django model.

Everything works perfectly except that if cell have some formatting of "superscript" or "subscript" it loses that formatting.

Is there a way to preserve the style formatting of the value in the cell?

m<sup>2</sup> becomes simply m2

Comment: There is no formating *superscript*? I think it's `unicode` encoded, looks like django looses `unicode` encoding.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by unicode loss. If I open the xml in xlsx file I see the tag vertAlign val="superscript".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing workbooks with rich text in openpyxl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774757/editing-workbooks-with-rich-text-in-openpyxl)

Answer (score 2):

> If I open the xml in xlsx file I see the tag vertAlign val="superscript"
>
> **Comments:** I have to use Python 2 and openpyxl 2.2. And the cell value is not just '2' or '3' it is 'm^2' or 'm^3' or what ever,

This is *Character Format*, you **can't** pass **Character Format** to Django.
Only the value which ist **^2 or ^3**.

For instance this would help:

```
import re
if vertAlign == superscript:
    value = re.sub('\^2', '²', cell.value)
    value = re.sub('\^3', '³', value)
```

This changes **all** simulated *superscipt(2|3)*, to unicode(²|³).

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***
Should also work with your **Python 2 and openpyxl 2.2**.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this doesn't work for me. I have to use Python 2 and openpyxl 2.2. And the cell value is not just '2' or '3' it is 'm^2' or 'm^3' or what ever, it can contain more then 2 characters along with formatting only one of them. It looks like I have to write a custom parser for this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the version of openpyxl being used.