# How to format text as subscript in openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, format, openpyxl

I need to output some text into excel format with openpyxl. I want some of my texts as subscripts and others as superscripts.

I have checked the documentation for openpyxl but can't find anything about that. I did find the `openpyxl.cell.text` module [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.4/api/openpyxl.cell.text.html#openpyxl-cell-text-module).

This code runs fine

```
wb = OP.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

c = OP.cell.text.InlineFont(vertAlign='subscript')
ws.cell(row=1, column=1, value='ab')

wb.save('example.xlsx')
```

But I don't know how I can use `c` to make text appear as subscript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing workbooks with rich text in openpyxl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774757/editing-workbooks-with-rich-text-in-openpyxl)

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import the right modules.

This one works:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, Protection, Font
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
a = ws['A1']
ws['A1'] =  'appel'
a.font = Font(bold=True, vertAlign='subscript')
wb.save('test.xlsx')
```