# Python: openpyxl change font to bold

Tags: python, excel, fonts, openpyxl

I'm using Python version 3.6 and the latest version of the openxlpy module (v2.4.8) on Windows.

I want to change certain font to bold in a cell, but I don't want all the text contained in the cell to be bold. In short, I'm saving data to a new Excel workbook that I've created using openxlpy. I'm saving multiple lines of data in one cell. I only want the first line of each cell to be bold.

I've searched everywhere in the openpyxl documentation and online but I can't find anything. It appears to me that you can only apply font styling to the entire cell which doesn't seem right. In Microsoft Excel you can apply different font styles to different data within one cell.

In summary, I want to only bold certain text in a cell and not bold the entire contents of the cell.

Comment: Can you loop through the characters in a cell with `openxlpy`?  Perhaps get a cell's data/info, then loop through the characters in that?

Comment: I could loop through the characters.I don't think that would help me though, I think with openpyxl you have to set the entire cell's contents bold for example.

I'm hoping someone tells me otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing workbooks with rich text in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774757/editing-workbooks-with-rich-text-in-openpyxl)

Answer (score 34):

Answers post title but not ops specific question.

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['B3'] = "Hello"
ws['B3'].font = Font(bold=True)
wb.save("BoldDemo.xlsx")
```

[image: Screendump of openpyxl BoldDemo]

Comment: @CharlieClark - Another example demonstrating the activecell bug. https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1026/set-active-cell

Comment: How do I implement, different text colors for different words in a cell

Answer (score 1):

I do not think openpyxl has implemented any handling for intracell style differences. If you take a file that has multiple styles in one cell, import it in openpyxl and save it new file, without changing the cell, the new file will lose its formatting.

```
>>>import openpyxl
>>>path = 'test.xlsx'
>>>book = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
>>>book.active['a1']
>>>book.active['a1'].value
'not bold line\nbold line\nnot bold line\n'
>>>print(_)
not bold line
bold line
not bold line

>>>book.save(path)
```

[image: image with bold]

[image]

From here you have a couple options.

1. Use another lib for handling xlsx.
   I will refrain from talking about using alternative libraries because I'm presuming you are using openpyxl for a reason.
2. Create your own markdown and use a custom script to add the formatting after editing and saving the file with openpyxl.
   You can find the spec for Office Open XML File Formats [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm).
   Here is a also a great article about parsing xlsx files and xml.
3. edit the codebase for openpyxl.
4. If the steps above are not achievable/desirable, try to contact the openpyxl maintainers, or hire help :/

Comment: Formatting below the level of the cell is not supported by openpyxl [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28793251/4539999)

Comment: book.active['a1'].value = CellRichText(https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rich_text.html)