# How to keep style format unchanged after writing data using openxlsx in R

Tags: r

I am using openxlsx in order to write the outputs of my data.

I have used the following code to read my data using readxl.

```html
df1=read_excel("C:/my_data.xlsx",skip=2);
```

Now I want to write the output and keep the original Excel file using any possible package.  I have used the following codes, but it does not keep the original Excel file. Can we do it it in R packages?

```html
 write.xlsx(df1, 'C:/mydata.xlsx',skip=2)
```

Comment: when you say it didn't keep  the original file, can you be more specific

Comment: For example, fonts, colours, ...

Comment: Can you check [here](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx/issues/83)

Answer (score 0):

Given your code, you should nhave **two** different data files in your working directory:
*"my_data.xlsx"* (the one that you loaded), and *"mydata.xlsx"* (the one that you created through R). R shouldn't overwrite your files if you give them different names.

If there's only one file, are you sure you didn't use the same name for both files? If so, then everything should work fine if you give the files different names (e.g. *"my_file1.xlsx"* and *"my_file2.xlsx"*)!

Also, in general, it's a good idea to give data files an informative name so that you don't accidentally delete/overwrite files that you need. For example, if the original excel data is you raw data, consider naming it "data_raw.xlsx", and make sure that you only read it, and whenever you make some changes to it, save it under a different name (e.g. *"data_processed1.xlsx"*).

You can also save data files in the native R format `.rds` using the `save_rds()` function, this is especially helpful if you want to keep special attributes of variables such as factors, etc...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I do not think your comments are correct. I have already done all your comments, but I did not get the same style format.Kindly read my description correctly

Comment: If it's about style/formatting, i.e. font/colours etc...then I can't help you, sorry. However, using formating in spreadsheets to convey information (e.g. having profits in green & losses in red) is *not* a good data management practice. It makes it easier to make mistakes, lose information, and makes your data less portable.

Comment: See https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2017.1375989