# Is there a python/openpyxl function to read an excel containing links to other workbooks, keeping the right format in the cell value?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, reference, external, openpyxl

By reading the last answer to the question: 
[How to keep style format unchanged after writing data using OpenPyXL package in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52878615/how-to-keep-style-format-unchanged-after-writing-data-using-openpyxl-package-in/60004217#60004217)

I see there is an XML file which contains metadata from Excel, including external links to other excelworkbooks. Thanks for such a good explanation.

After using `load_workbook`, when I get the cell value of a cell containing a formula with a reference to other workbook, that referred workbook file name is replaced by a sort of index ([2] / [3] in the example which follows):

```
=H8+E5+G7+'s1'!$E$5+[2]Sheet1!$D$1+[3]Sheet1!$D$5
```

I need to obtain that formula with the real workbookname (all the referred excel workbooks are in the same folder as the one I am handling), something like this:

```
=H8+E5+G7+'s1'!$E$5+'s2.xlsm'Sheet1!$D$1+'s1.xlsm'Sheet1!$D$5
```

I have seen the option `keep links`, but I don't manage to get those links to be part of the formula of the cell.

Is there a way to keep the real cell value with references to other workbooks when reading the cell in the origin workbook?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: The code for managing external links does manage such references but you'll have to work out how to use it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the information Charlie Clark. Do you mean that there is not any method/function already implemented and I will need to patch/modify the standard openpyxl source code?