# How to set superscript using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl 2.5.12 and python 2.7. I am using a excel template and need to retain the format of headers. There are some superscript values like Summary^2 that just end up as Summary2. I understand that styles are set at a cell level in openpyxl. Is there any other workaround for this? i really need this since there are many headers and footnotes as superscripts

tried setting different styles, but it either makes the whole cell value as superscript or none. Not just the last value as needed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing workbooks with rich text in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774757/editing-workbooks-with-rich-text-in-openpyxl)

Answer (score 0):

This code assigns the alignment of your text to `superscript`  which basiclly means "make this cell superscript" to openpyxl

```py
#Import openpyxl
from openpyxl import *

#Get the workbook and set the work sheet
workbook = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

#Add some data
ws.append(['Hello', 'World'])

#Change vertAlign so that the text is superscript
ws['A1'].vertAlign = "superscript"

#Save the workbook
workbook.save('file_name.xlsx')
```

EDIT: This can be done in [xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_rich_strings.html). So what you're looking to do is:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('rich_strings.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30)
superscript = workbook.add_format({'font_script': 1})
worksheet.write_rich_string('cell',
                            'hello',
                            superscript, 'world'
)
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, but this is something i know and i mentioned in my question. my question was more how to keep 'hello' as normal and 'world' as superscript when they are both in the same cell

Comment: It seems that rich text formatting (basically what you're trying to do) has not been added in openpyxl. You should open an issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/chronossc/openpyxl/issues)

Comment: Found an issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/chronossc/openpyxl/issues/46)

Comment: @D3110 edited my answer and now it has a fix, might not work with Python 2, it's reached it's end of life though so you should upgrade.