# What's the simplest way of changing the color of single characters?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to write some data to an Excel file. I'm able to change the text color of whole cells using the Font class, but what about changing the color of single characters from a string?

Comment: You can't do this with openpyxl.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Editing workbooks with rich text in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774757/editing-workbooks-with-rich-text-in-openpyxl)