# how to detect strikethrough data using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

I am reading data from an excel sheet, i need to ignore/filter out any data which is strikethrough. How to detect strikethrough style? I am using openpyxl. If there is no way, then can i open the worksheet via xlrd, i mean can i open the excel sheet via both of them and still get the desired ouput?
or has anyone made a specific parser for it?

Comment: I had also the same problem and used for the most parts xlrd . For getting some basic informations like name of the cols I worked with openpyxl. If you now the the col and row index you can just get the information from another object. Whether this might be senseful depends on your whole code. And some really good working code you find her: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371787/how-do-i-find-the-formatting-for-a-subset-of-text-in-an-excel-document-cell