# determine bold font with Python xlrd

Tags: python, excel, fonts

I know I can create bold font in excel (`.xlsx` files) using Python `xlsxwriter` package.

I'm reading and processing excel files with Python `xlrd` package. Is that possible for me to determine if a cell is using bold font or not?

I did some search and some posts say font attributes is not yet implemented in Python `xlrd` package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the formatting for a subset of text in an Excel document cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371787/how-do-i-find-the-formatting-for-a-subset-of-text-in-an-excel-document-cell)

Comment: No, xlrd doesn't read the formatting information in .xlsx files.