# Color some lines of text in existing file using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I was wondering if it was possible to color only some lines of text/characters with openpyxl and output them on the same excel sheet?

Example:

```
The dog is red. The man is blue. My favorite color is black.
```

To:

```
The dog is [blue] red [/blue]. The man is [blue] blue [/blue] . My favorite color is [blue] yellow [/blue].
```

I have the strings and position of the strings that need to be in color, and even if it's the same color (blue or green) it would be fine.

Thanks!

Note: `[blue] [/blue]` means the color within the brackets are blue.

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774757/editing-workbooks-with-rich-text-in-openpyxl), `openpyxl` does not support formatting before cell level. You can however try `xlrd` which is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371787/how-do-i-find-the-formatting-for-a-subset-of-text-in-an-excel-document-cell).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing workbooks with rich text in openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774757/editing-workbooks-with-rich-text-in-openpyxl)