# How to get each char format from XLSX cell with xlrd?

Tags: python, excel, reverse-engineering, openpyxl, xlrd

I have an excel with format like this:

[image]

and I read this cell using python:

```
wb = open_workbook(xlsx_path,formatting_info=True)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
cell = sheet.cell(i,j)
print("cell.xf_index is", cell.xf_index)
fmt = wb.xf_list[cell.xf_index]
print("type(fmt) is", type(fmt))
print("Dumped Info:")
fmt.dump()
```

but what I get is wholly cell format:

[image]

how can I get each char format? thanks!

Comment: What library are you using to access the spreadsheet using Python?

Comment: Please post the .xlsx file. You may have better luck using openpyxl. I'll code up an example if you post the .xlsx file.

Comment: @ScottHunter  I use xlrd library

Comment: Put it somewhere from where I can download it and post the link here.

Comment: @vy32 here it is & very thanks! -> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F7F4_uFprxG0tPkkXXd3SMplslK4po5y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have examined your spreadsheet and have created my own, which you can find here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WBm_tcFdlcckDgIvPdh-ezosm5pP4xXd

Here is what mine looks like:

[image]

My fonts are sized 11, 22, 33 and 44 point, to make it easier to find them.

I have been unable to find an API in either `xlrd` or in `openpyxl` that lets us read the multiple fonts stored in a single cell. However, I know that `openpyxl` offers this functionality. The problem is that this aspect of `openpyxl` is not well documented.

I attempted to reverse engineer the file format. Recall the `.xlsx` files are ZIP files. So I unzipped it. Here is the contents of my Sheet1.xml file, prettyprinted:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" xmlns:xr2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/revision2" xmlns:xr3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision3" mc:Ignorable="x14ac xr xr2 xr3" xr:uid="{5F15C188-96B2-E44D-B28B-DB5F2AE0283E}">
  <dimension ref="A1"/>
  <sheetViews>
    <sheetView tabSelected="1" zoomScale="352" zoomScaleNormal="352" workbookViewId="0"/>
  </sheetViews>
  <sheetFormatPr baseColWidth="10" defaultRowHeight="16"/>
  <sheetData>
    <row r="1" spans="1:1" ht="57">
      <c r="A1" s="1" t="s">
        <v>0</v>
      </c>
    </row>
  </sheetData>
  <pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3"/>
</worksheet>
```

For comparison, here is yours:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" xmlns:xr2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/revision2" xmlns:xr3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision3" mc:Ignorable="x14ac xr xr2 xr3" xr:uid="{6A0965C4-B0BC-435B-932C-B62A46E63DFA}">
  <dimension ref="A1"/>
  <sheetViews>
    <sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0"/>
  </sheetViews>
  <sheetFormatPr defaultRowHeight="16.5" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25"/>
  <sheetData>
    <row r="1" spans="1:1" ht="25.5" x14ac:dyDescent="0.25">
      <c r="A1" t="s">
        <v>0</v>
      </c>
    </row>
  </sheetData>
  <phoneticPr fontId="1" type="noConversion"/>
  <pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3"/>
</worksheet>
```

As you can see, the style information is not stored in Sheet1.xml. Instead, it is stored in `styles.xml`. It appears that Excel creates a named style for a cell that has specialized formatting applied. A named style can contain any of the formatting things that a cell can have, such as fonts and fills.

So here is what the `styles.xml` file looks like for a blank Excel file:

```xml
<styleSheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" xmlns:x16r2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/02/main" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" mc:Ignorable="x14ac x16r2 xr">
  <fonts count="1" x14ac:knownFonts="1">
    <font>
      <sz val="12"/>
      <color theme="1"/>
      <name val="Calibri"/>
      <family val="2"/>
      <scheme val="minor"/>
    </font>
  </fonts>
  <fills count="2">
    <fill>
      <patternFill patternType="none"/>
    </fill>
    <fill>
      <patternFill patternType="gray125"/>
    </fill>
  </fills>
  <borders count="1">
    <border>
      <left/>
      <right/>
      <top/>
      <bottom/>
      <diagonal/>
    </border>
  </borders>
  <cellStyleXfs count="1">
    <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0"/>
  </cellStyleXfs>
  <cellXfs count="1">
    <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0"/>
  </cellXfs>
  <cellStyles count="1">
    <cellStyle name="Normal" xfId="0" builtinId="0"/>
  </cellStyles>
  <dxfs count="0"/>
  <tableStyles count="0" defaultTableStyle="TableStyleMedium2" defaultPivotStyle="PivotStyleLight16"/>
  <extLst>
    <ext xmlns:x14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main" uri="{EB79DEF2-80B8-43e5-95BD-54CBDDF9020C}">
      <x14:slicerStyles defaultSlicerStyle="SlicerStyleLight1"/>
    </ext>
    <ext xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main" uri="{9260A510-F301-46a8-8635-F512D64BE5F5}">
      <x15:timelineStyles defaultTimelineStyle="TimeSlicerStyleLight1"/>
    </ext>
  </extLst>
</styleSheet>
```

And here is the one for my file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<styleSheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" xmlns:x16r2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/02/main" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" mc:Ignorable="x14ac x16r2 xr">
  <fonts count="6">
    <font>
      <sz val="12"/>
      <color theme="1"/>
      <name val="Calibri"/>
      <family val="2"/>
      <scheme val="minor"/>
    </font>
    <font>
      <sz val="11"/>
      <color theme="1"/>
      <name val="Calibri (Body)_x0000_"/>
    </font>
    <font>
      <sz val="12"/>
      <color theme="1"/>
      <name val="Calibri (Body)_x0000_"/>
    </font>
    <font>
      <sz val="44"/>
      <color rgb="FFFF0000"/>
      <name val="Calibri (Body)_x0000_"/>
    </font>
    <font>
      <sz val="33"/>
      <color rgb="FF0070C0"/>
      <name val="Calibri (Body)_x0000_"/>
    </font>
    <font>
      <sz val="22"/>
      <color rgb="FF7030A0"/>
      <name val="Calibri (Body)_x0000_"/>
    </font>
  </fonts>
  <fills count="2">
    <fill>
      <patternFill patternType="none"/>
    </fill>
    <fill>
      <patternFill patternType="gray125"/>
    </fill>
  </fills>
  <borders count="1">
    <border>
      <left/>
      <right/>
      <top/>
      <bottom/>
      <diagonal/>
    </border>
  </borders>
  <cellStyleXfs count="1">
    <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0"/>
  </cellStyleXfs>
  <cellXfs count="2">
    <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0"/>
    <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="2" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0" applyFont="1"/>
  </cellXfs>
  <cellStyles count="1">
    <cellStyle name="Normal" xfId="0" builtinId="0"/>
  </cellStyles>
  <dxfs count="0"/>
  <tableStyles count="0" defaultTableStyle="TableStyleMedium2" defaultPivotStyle="PivotStyleLight16"/>
  <extLst>
    <ext xmlns:x14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main" uri="{EB79DEF2-80B8-43e5-95BD-54CBDDF9020C}">
      <x14:slicerStyles defaultSlicerStyle="SlicerStyleLight1"/>
    </ext>
    <ext xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main" uri="{9260A510-F301-46a8-8635-F512D64BE5F5}">
      <x15:timelineStyles defaultTimelineStyle="TimeSlicerStyleLight1"/>
    </ext>
  </extLst>
</styleSheet>
```

And here is yours:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<styleSheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac" xmlns:x16r2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/02/main" xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision" mc:Ignorable="x14ac x16r2 xr">
  <fonts count="4" x14ac:knownFonts="1">
    <font>
      <sz val="12"/>
      <color theme="1"/>
      <name val="新細明體"/>
      <family val="2"/>
      <charset val="136"/>
      <scheme val="minor"/>
    </font>
    <font>
      <sz val="9"/>
      <name val="新細明體"/>
      <family val="2"/>
      <charset val="136"/>
      <scheme val="minor"/>
    </font>
    <font>
      <sz val="18"/>
      <color rgb="FFFF0000"/>
      <name val="新細明體"/>
      <family val="1"/>
      <charset val="136"/>
      <scheme val="minor"/>
    </font>
    <font>
      <b/>
      <sz val="16"/>
      <color theme="1"/>
      <name val="新細明體"/>
      <family val="1"/>
      <charset val="136"/>
      <scheme val="minor"/>
    </font>
  </fonts>
  <fills count="2">
    <fill>
      <patternFill patternType="none"/>
    </fill>
    <fill>
      <patternFill patternType="gray125"/>
    </fill>
  </fills>
  <borders count="1">
    <border>
      <left/>
      <right/>
      <top/>
      <bottom/>
      <diagonal/>
    </border>
  </borders>
  <cellStyleXfs count="1">
    <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0">
      <alignment vertical="center"/>
    </xf>
  </cellStyleXfs>
  <cellXfs count="1">
    <xf numFmtId="0" fontId="0" fillId="0" borderId="0" xfId="0">
      <alignment vertical="center"/>
    </xf>
  </cellXfs>
  <cellStyles count="1">
    <cellStyle name="一般" xfId="0" builtinId="0"/>
  </cellStyles>
  <dxfs count="0"/>
  <tableStyles count="0" defaultTableStyle="TableStyleMedium2" defaultPivotStyle="PivotStyleLight16"/>
  <extLst>
    <ext xmlns:x14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main"
         uri="{EB79DEF2-80B8-43e5-95BD-54CBDDF9020C}">
      <x14:slicerStyles defaultSlicerStyle="SlicerStyleLight1"/>
    </ext>
    <ext xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main"
         uri="{9260A510-F301-46a8-8635-F512D64BE5F5}">
      <x15:timelineStyles defaultTimelineStyle="TimeSlicerStyleLight1"/>
    </ext>
  </extLst>
</styleSheet>
```

So now you can see why my file is easier to work with, at least for me: the font sizes 11, 22, 33 and 44 are easy to find in the XML! (Mine also has names in English (which I speak), and not in Chinese (which I don't)).

So in my example there are six fonts (I'm not clear what purpose `count="6"` serves), and my example has fonts 0, 4, 5, and 3, in that order.

My problem at this point is I can't find where the list of fonts, in order, gets bound to the cell.

Oh, here's a program I wrote to decode the spreadsheet with `openpyxl`, but I didn't get very far:

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import sys

if __name__=="__main__":
    wb = load_workbook(sys.argv[1])
    for ws in wb.worksheets:
        print(f"Sheet {ws} max rows: {ws.max_row} max cols: {ws.max_column}")
        for row in range(0,ws.max_row):
            for column in range(0,ws.max_column):
                # Note that openpyxl starts at 1 for rows and columns
                cell = ws.cell(row=row+1, column=column+1)
                print(cell)
                print(dir(cell))
                for attr in dir(cell):
                    if attr[0]!='_':
                        print(f"cell {attr} = {getattr(cell,attr)}")
                        print("")
        print("ws['A1'].style=",ws['A1'].style)
    print(dir(wb))
    print(wb.named_styles)
    style = wb.named_styles[0]
    print(style)
```

and here is the output:

```
Sheet <Worksheet "Sheet1"> max rows: 1 max cols: 1
<Cell 'Sheet1'.A1>
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_bind_value', '_comment', '_hyperlink', '_style', '_value', 'alignment', 'base_date', 'border', 'check_error', 'check_string', 'col_idx', 'column', 'column_letter', 'comment', 'coordinate', 'data_type', 'encoding', 'fill', 'font', 'guess_types', 'has_style', 'hyperlink', 'internal_value', 'is_date', 'number_format', 'offset', 'parent', 'pivotButton', 'protection', 'quotePrefix', 'row', 'style', 'style_id', 'value']
cell alignment = <openpyxl.styles.alignment.Alignment object>
Parameters:
horizontal=None, vertical=None, textRotation=0, wrapText=None, shrinkToFit=None, indent=0.0, relativeIndent=0.0, justifyLastLine=None, readingOrder=0.0

cell base_date = 2415018.5

cell border = <openpyxl.styles.borders.Border object>
Parameters:
outline=True, diagonalUp=False, diagonalDown=False, start=None, end=None, left=<openpyxl.styles.borders.Side object>
Parameters:
style=None, color=None, right=<openpyxl.styles.borders.Side object>
Parameters:
style=None, color=None, top=<openpyxl.styles.borders.Side object>
Parameters:
style=None, color=None, bottom=<openpyxl.styles.borders.Side object>
Parameters:
style=None, color=None, diagonal=<openpyxl.styles.borders.Side object>
Parameters:
style=None, color=None, vertical=None, horizontal=None

cell check_error = <bound method Cell.check_error of <Cell 'Sheet1'.A1>>

cell check_string = <bound method Cell.check_string of <Cell 'Sheet1'.A1>>

cell col_idx = 1

cell column = 1

cell column_letter = A

cell comment = None

cell coordinate = A1

cell data_type = s

cell encoding = utf-8

cell fill = <openpyxl.styles.fills.PatternFill object>
Parameters:
patternType=None, fgColor=<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='00000000', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb', bgColor=<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb='00000000', indexed=None, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='rgb'

cell font = <openpyxl.styles.fonts.Font object>
Parameters:
name='Calibri (Body)_x0000_', charset=None, family=None, b=False, i=False, strike=None, outline=None, shadow=None, condense=None, color=<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb=None, indexed=None, auto=None, theme=1, tint=0.0, type='theme', extend=None, sz=12.0, u=None, vertAlign=None, scheme=None

cell guess_types = False

cell has_style = True

cell hyperlink = None

cell internal_value = test

cell is_date = False

cell number_format = General

cell offset = <bound method Cell.offset of <Cell 'Sheet1'.A1>>

cell parent = <Worksheet "Sheet1">

cell pivotButton = False

cell protection = <openpyxl.styles.protection.Protection object>
Parameters:
locked=True, hidden=False

cell quotePrefix = False

cell row = 1

cell style = Normal

cell style_id = 1

cell value = test

ws['A1'].style= Normal
['_Workbook__write_only', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_active_sheet_index', '_add_sheet', '_alignments', '_borders', '_cell_styles', '_colors', '_data_only', '_date_formats', '_differential_styles', '_external_links', '_fills', '_fonts', '_named_styles', '_number_formats', '_pivots', '_protections', '_read_only', '_setup_styles', '_sheets', '_table_styles', 'active', 'add_named_range', 'add_named_style', 'calculation', 'chartsheets', 'close', 'code_name', 'copy_worksheet', 'create_chartsheet', 'create_named_range', 'create_sheet', 'data_only', 'defined_names', 'encoding', 'epoch', 'excel_base_date', 'get_active_sheet', 'get_index', 'get_named_range', 'get_named_ranges', 'get_sheet_by_name', 'get_sheet_names', 'guess_types', 'index', 'is_template', 'iso_dates', 'loaded_theme', 'mime_type', 'move_sheet', 'named_styles', 'path', 'properties', 'read_only', 'rels', 'remove', 'remove_named_range', 'remove_sheet', 'save', 'security', 'shared_strings', 'sheetnames', 'style_names', 'template', 'vba_archive', 'views', 'worksheets', 'write_only']
['Normal']
Normal
```

Here are some references I consulted which I thought would help:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cellstyleformats?view=openxml-2.8.1
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6fe3ff0-152e-4398-9d17-fee8476ae466/how-to-understand-the-process-of-cell-formatting-?forum=os_binaryfile
- https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Cell_Style_in_Xls_module
- https://c-rex.net/projects/samples/ooxml/e1/Part4/OOXML_P4_DOCX_cellStyleXfs_topic_ID0EXX65.html
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/708978af-b598-45c4-a598-d3518a5a09f0/howwhen-is-cellstylexfs-vs-cellxfs-applied-to-a-cell?forum=os_binaryfile

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I got the point. I think I can parser the .xml file to get format I want

Comment: If you figure out the linkage, please let me know!

Comment: finally I got this easier & work for me->> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371787/how-do-i-find-the-formatting-for-a-subset-of-text-in-an-excel-document-cell

Comment: Xlwings will allow you to manipulate individual chararacters with a cell; font, colour, super/sub script, strikethrough etc